# Subclassing UIApplication to override sendEvent causes crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios4

I'm trying subclass UIApplication to catch all touch event, this is used to see if user is afk or not. Anyway it works great first time you launch the application. If you put it in background and open it again 2 times then it crashes. I have no idea what causes this. I'm getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on [super sendEvent:event];

My Subclass MyUI:

```
@implementation MyUI

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event]; // <-- EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

    if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches) {
        UITouch *touch = [event allTouches].anyObject;
        if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
           // Calling some methods
        }
     }
}  
@end
```

Main.m

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSString* appClass = @"MyUI";
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, appClass, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: can you add a stack trace? I am using the same approach in my app to track every touch event, and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get exact reason for EXEC_BAD_ACCESS use nszombieenabled in your application.
This link will guide you for using it.
 http://iosdevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html

Comment: Can you please explain where you had leak ? I have the same problem

Comment: Exactly; if this answer helped you find the problem, please update your question or add a comment explaining what the cause was/how you solved it. It might help other people!

Answer (score 6):

Is there a reason the super class method is being called first? If you are intercepting, you should be calling it last.

That might be your problem. I also override sendEvent to intercept all events to my application and have no issues.

If you call the super method first it will pass it to all UIResponders that may eventually eat your event resulting in the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. Furthermore as DavidNeiss suggests eliminate the lines below the super call. If you still receive the bad access signal its likely another view or controller down the line causing it. You'll need to stack trace to find out where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Dont understand what "afk" means.

Another approach might be to create a custom gesture recognizer. They (gesture recognizers) are supposed to filter through touch events before they are forwarded to the view as part of the normal touches event processing.

Comment: afk means away from keyboard. In other word i'm checking if the user are still useing the ipad/iphone or if user is away.

Comment: Ok, so the UIApplication class forwards the events to the UIWindow. What if instead of subclassing UIApplication, you subclass UIWindow and stick your processing in its - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event method. I've tried that and added a NSLog()/[super sendEvent:event] to mine and seen events coming out.

Comment: Also, for the way you are doing it, if you just have the "    [super sendEvent:event]; // <-- EXEC_BAD_ACCESS" line and get rid of the stuff you added below it, does it crash? If so, then something is messed up because you shouldn't really be changing things with that. I would back that change out and see if its still crashing then.

Answer (score 1):

Just for simplicity's sake, I would put the @"MyUI" directly into the UIApplicationMain call.

The string is most likely your problem. It's outside of the `NSAutoreleasePool`, and that is just not done.

In addition, the name @"MyUI" hints at a view controller, not an AppDelegate class. Look into that.

Answer (score 1):

[super sendEvent:event]; // <-- EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

means error is in your class.

For testing block

```
/*
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event]; // <-- EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

    if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches) {
        UITouch *touch = [event allTouches].anyObject;
        if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
           // Calling some methods
        }
     }
} 
*/
```

still you will get that error. Any time if you are getting error while override sendEvent
try to block all override method and check still you are getting that error or not specially for this line `[super sendEvent:event];`. I had also stuck with this error and figured out no mistake in this method. Mistake was found in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Always keep your code within try catch method

```
@try {

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception => %@",exception);
}
```

This will help you figure out right problem.

Comment: Adding a generic exception breakpoint (that caches all exceptions in Xcode) is a much better solution than wrapping your code in try catch.